# Two chrome extensions using AngularJS and sharing the Gmail DOM crashing both

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that injects functionality into the Gmail DOM that works fine when no other extensions are also trying to do the same. I need to use angular.bootstrap to bootstrap my injected HTML code since it is dynamic after the page has been rendered by gmail initially as I think all extensions that operate in gmail do.

As soon as another extension in gmail that also uses angular attempts to bootstrap itself, it does so at the top HTML tag and basically injects over the top of my bootstrapped code and generates an error in the bootstrapping routine: `Uncaught Error: [ng:btstrpd] App Already Bootstrapped with this Element`

Then, even worse, both apps are actually sharing the scope in some strange way so that neither functions properly after that (The angular core code starts crashing around mutating the DOM for bindings, etc.).

It would appear that since both of us are operating in our own sandboxes at least partially and trying to bootstrap at the top level that there is no way to detect and/or prevent this overlap. Do I have any options here?